# Debug python library

Tags: python, github, pycharm, collaboration

I have no idea how to debut a library without installing it, I want to enhance [this](https://github.com/flyingrub/scdl) library, but if I run PyCharm with this configuration:
[Pycharm debug configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCNr8.png)

I never collaborated on github or similar, however I decided to join this Hacktoberfest. What configuration should I use? In case I have to install it, how can I put the breakpoints easily?

Edit for more info:

Package has 3 modules:

```
scdl
|
|-------- client.py
|--------------- scdl.py
|--------------------utils.py
```

When I run the scdl.py module which has a main it tries to import the client and utils modules, however It can't find them for some reason, I tried to add the directory where the scdl package is stored to the PYTHONPATH variable, and still got no result

[Screenshot of PyCharm Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsUiv.png)

The error is:

```
    from scdl import client, utils
ImportError: cannot import name 'client'
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem. Why does your current configuration not work?

Comment: Sorry I should added more info.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the directory inside of pycharm and the exact error message you get?

Comment: The error: 
```
    from scdl import client, utils
ImportError: cannot import name 'client'
```

Comment: From the Terminal positioned at the root of your project: Does `python -m scdl.scdl` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working on something that's intended to be a module, I usually install the module in my interpretter then use the "module_name" run configuration in PyCharm instead of the "script_path" like you have set up.

1. Create a virtual environment: `python -m venv venv`
2. Activate the virtual environment: `source venv/bin/activate`
3. Follow the instructions in the projects readme to install (in this case `python setup.py install`)
4. Add that virtual environment to PyCharm (Preferences > Project Interpreter)
5. PyCharm will prompt you to install requirements, do it
6. Where it says "script_path" in your run configuration, click the little arrow and change to "module_name"
7. Set the module name to "scdl.scdl"

Now you should be able to run/debug as normal, hope that helps!

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Ty! :)

Comment: No problem! Had to update a couple pieces (like the module name) so hopefully you read the final version D: